# Email field does not show up when I view node, only when I edit

Tags: 7, entities

I have an email field in an entity. The text field is there when I edit the entity but it does not display when I view the entity. How do I get it to display when viewing?

Comment: Have you checked 'display fields' in your content types settings?

Comment: got this to show up by changing the label display from above to inline. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check 'display fields' in your content type settings.